# Preventing Swift class from appearing in Swift-To-Objc bridging header

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods, bridging-header

I am using the Pod [FSPagerView](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSPagerView). This pod includes the class `FSPagerViewCell` that inherits from `UICollectionViewCell`, and I have a Swift class `MyCell` that inherits from `FSPagerViewCell`.

The problem is that my class appears in the bridging header but I receive the following error message:

> Cannot find interface declaration for 'FSPagerViewCell', superclass
>   of 'MyCell'

I trying to do one the following:

1. Make the `FSPagerViewCell` class to be found in the bridging header
2. Prevent `MyCell` from appearing in the bridging header.

I am not able to do any of the two things. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: i believe what the error means is where ever you are using MyCell you need to import FSPagerView

Comment: Did you ever find out how to exclude the class from the Bridging Header?